# How to automate applying custom patches to ubuntu upstream packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, patch, debuild

I have a local customization to the `xserver-xorg-core` package. It is a patch I have created and is not useful to anyone else since it is an optimization very specific to my workflow.

So, whenever I run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and `xserver-xorg-core` is upgraded, I need to perform these steps:

- run `apt-get source xserver-xorg-core`
- run `patch -p1 < mypatch.diff` to apply my customization
- run `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck debuild -us -uc -i -I` to build the package
- run `cd .. && sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to replace the upstream package with my customized version

Since my patch is very small, is is very likely it will work across multiple versions, yet I have to repeat these steps every time. Is there a better way to manage patches to upstream packages?

Comment: Seems like a shell script could handle it...